# Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova - updating a plugin code not published

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am using vs2015 and creating a cordova project of android.
I downloaded one of the core plugins (using the config.xml).
I made some changes to the js file of this plugin.

Then I rebuild the app and run on Ripple, the updated code is not published.
on the folder: platforms\android\platform_www\plugins  the new code is not deployed...

why?

Comment: i think the updating of plugins is not done correctly, you can delete the android platform and can rebuild again

Comment: so  every update delete the platform? should I open a bug?  is there another tool for plugin dev?

Comment: No Need there is a Update for the Platform, this issue got noticed by MS Team please follow this [blog](http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/)

Comment: the link was poinint to 7, found update 8 here: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release-update-8/ .  nay way thanks a lot!

Comment: I upgraded to 8 and unfortunately still have the same issue :-(

Comment: If i delete the platform folder and then rebuild, the folder - \platforms\android\assets\www\plugins  is not beeing rebuild again... (also the config.xml and cordova_plugins.js)
So the plugin is not working.
is there any way to talk with the dev team?

Comment: try to clear the Cachce from the `Tools->Options->Tools for apacheCordova->ClearCordovacache`

Comment: did no help... :-(

Comment: in this path try to see your plugin in and try to add the code manually and build again `\platforms\android\assets\www\plugins`

Answer (score 0):

If you target an Android device or Emulator you will see the platform\android\ files created. When you target Ripple, a simulated build is performed for local testing in your browser, but it's not the same as a full Android build.